# Android: Imagebutton I set programatically are distored in size

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

this is like the x-time that I am doing this however today nothing works.

Im basically doing this:

```
ImageButton btnComments = new ImageButton(this);
            ImageButton btngreenLikes = new ImageButton(this);
            ImageButton btnblueLikes = new ImageButton(this);

            btnComments.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.comments_small);
            btngreenLikes.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.upvote_green);
            btnblueLikes.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.upvote_blue);


            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpWrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                 (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            btnComments.LayoutParameters = lpWrap;
            btngreenLikes.LayoutParameters = lpWrap;
            btnblueLikes.LayoutParameters = lpWrap;


            linlayForImages.AddView(btnComments);
            linlayForImages.AddView(btngreenLikes);
            linlayForImages.AddView(btnblueLikes);
```

Set add thre imagebuttons in within my code. Give all three a background resource, then set their layout to WRAP CONTENT in HEIGHT and WIDTH.
And then add their views into my layout.

The result ist, they are everything BUT wrapped content. While the comment img is correct, th other two are distored. greenlikes is too big in total size and blue like is top big in width? I use those imagebutton resources in another activity where I set those with the xml and they are fine. So the resource is all clear. Can someone tell me what the HELL is going on here?

Comment: Your image resources aren't the same size.

Comment: no, they arent - but even when I only put up the blue likes one, it still is distorted. also, im using the exact same imageviews in another activity - all three of them - and there they are just fine :(

Answer (score 0):

Update: Naming my Imagebuttons Imageviews solved this issue. Don't!